# powershell pass variable socket to new job

Tags: powershell

This code works fine for me. it simple send data to socket

```
$buffer = New-Object byte[] 10

$Socket = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient( '127.0.0.1', 88)
 
$stream = $Socket.GetStream()
 
$writer = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter($stream)
 
$writer.Write($buffer, 0, 10)
$writer.Flush()
```

but when i want write data in new thread (job) it not work. not Write any data

```
$sb={
    
    $buffer = New-Object byte[] 10
    $writer = $args[0]
    $writer.Write($buffer, 0, 10)
    $writer.Flush()
}
 
     $Socket = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient( '127.0.0.1', 88)
 
     $Socket.NoDelay = $true
     
     $stream = $Socket.GetStream()
 
     $writer = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter($stream)
 
     start-job -ScriptBlock $sb -ArgumentList $writer
```

please help. i need send data in new thread

Comment: Can only assume `$stream` isn't being expanded?

Comment: i was try pass $stream and $Socket. no effect